# How to force https on every page in header

Tags: html, django, .htaccess

Is there a way to redirect visitors of a page from http to https without adjusting .htaaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should force the client to request HTTPS always with HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) headers:

```
// Use HTTP Strict Transport Security to force client to use secure connections only
$use_sts = true;

// iis sets HTTPS to 'off' for non-SSL requests
if ($use_sts && isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000');
} elseif ($use_sts) {
    header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true, 301);
    // we are in cleartext at the moment, prevent further execution and output
    die();
}
```

Please note that HSTS is supported in most modern browsers, but not universal. Thus the logic above manually redirects the user regardless of support if they end up on HTTP, and then sets the HSTS header so that further client requests should be redirected by the browser if possible.

Comment: Is there a non-php solution?

Comment: No .htaccess, no PHP. Something else...?

Comment: :) its a django based site that has no other php running. No need to mess it up with that. And trying to avoid .htaaccess because I don't want to get other team members involved...

Comment: @COMisHARD How about you add that information to the question itself...!?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` setting to True, [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#ssl-redirect) will permanently (HTTP 301) redirect all HTTP connections to HTTPS.